# Как работает сортировка (проверка) чисел методом sort()?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Подскажите, как происходит проверка в функции. Сначала сравниваются 40 и 100 (40-100 = -60, ничего не меняется) => Какие следующие числа попадают в функцию? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте консоль и посмотрите:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){
  console.log(a,b);
  return a-b;
});
```

В разных браузерах используются разные алгоритмы сортировки. [quicksort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Быстрая_сортировка) в частности Qsort, [merge sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_слиянием), [min sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_выбором)

Comment: большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!!